# Add an animation before a new intent in Android and remove the stock one

Tags: android, xml, animation, android-activity

I want to create a fluid animation when my app starts.

So I have 3 activities:

- SplashScreenActivity
- Activity that decides where to go (login, main_activity, etc...) (Let's call it RedirectorActivity)
- LoginActivity

I've already created a reduce_image.xml that reduce the image.

But now the problem arrives:
When the RedirectorActivity is the last Activity it shows the animation, but if I add:

```
Intent nextIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), LoginActivity.class);
            nextIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_ANIMATION);
            startActivity(nextIntent);
            overridePendingTransition(0, 0);
```

it removes the changingActivity animation (the stock card-like one), but also removes the transition that I've created in RedirectorActivity.

It's possible to do what am I thinking?

Answer (score 1):

Okay, I found the answer by myself.
After a walk to clean my ideas I remembered about:

> implements Animation.AnimationListener

With this I move the change-intent part inside of

```
@Override
public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {

}
```

Now it works.